# how to modify query params in a Jersey Filter

Tags: java, servlet-filters, jersey-2.0, query-string

According to [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)

> Filters can be used when you want to modify any request or response parameters like headers

So I believe modifying query params is possible but I don't know how and I haven't been able to find anything on Google or stackoverflow...

This the functionality I would like to achieve:

```
public class EreturnLookupFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserResource.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        // requestContext.setParameter("paramName", <new Value>);
    }
}
```

I am not keen to use prematching as I am linking this filter to a specific resource method so `requestContext.setRequestUri( builder.build() );` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939919/how-to-modify-queryparam-and-pathparam-in-jersey-2) is not an option for me.

thank you very much